# How can i get better crop marks in InDesign CC that are simpler to cut?

Tags: adobe-indesign, crop

I  know how to add regular crop marks to a design, my issue is when I go to cut out my prints on a paper cutter most of my crop marks are gone after 2 cuts so lining up the paper cutter gets really difficult. Is there any way to change the crop marks or an advanced crop mark script or something I can use on the latest version of InDesign?

I print out a number of labels and drawing lines on each one or using a knife to cut the inside out is kind of overkill. I remember someone turning the lines into a T (with a pen afterwards) so when you cut there are still lines inside you can use to guide you, just how would I do that in InDesign?

I sometimes do get me labels printed and would hate to have to make 2 versions just so i can print them myself. Would I really have to add in my own lines/custom crop marks in my document? Is there not enough people printing their own stuff to make a simpler solution?

[image]
<sub>(source: [printernational.org](http://www.printernational.org/images/articles/img-bleed-crop-marks.gif))</sub>

Comment: Take a pen and a ruler and draw the full lines on the top sheet only. Printing them visibly on every page kind of defeats their purpose - that they should not be visible after cutting.

Comment: If they are printed right you can remove any evidence with your last 2 cuts by cutting just a hair inside the line. If i turn my top marks into upside down Ts and the bottom marks into Ts and cut left and right sides first then when i cut the top and bottom i make sure to move it a hair out and I am all set!

Comment: @Joonas, I would argue that this is not a duplicate because I am looking for a way to programatically change the crop marks in InDesign versus knowing how to cut the crop marks InDesign gives me.

Comment: Sure, but the underlying issue is the same and there is no satisfying answer to your question. If you draw any additional lines, it defeats the purpose of using bleeds, you might as well drop the bleeds + crop marks and cut it with scissors. The selected answer in that question describes the simplest way to deal with crop marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal workflow for down-and-dirty "in-house" branded "gallery wall labels" which vary in size is to use an extra box that has a dotted rule at 1pt, set to black @ 20% tint/opacity. Vary the tint value so they are barely visible (I often work on gray laid paper).

I still use a straight edge, but all I need to do is drop the edge on the line and cut, which speeds things up quite a bit.

Note that unless you have a high-quality (read: professional) paper cutter, you will never get good straight edges. I have tried many types: guillotine, rack & slide etc and they all wiggle and nudge. Some paper cutters I have had to use can vary by 1/8 inch over 11 inches dues to curvature. Not helpful.

If you have a large number of identical sizes to cut, consider:

- making the box **a locked object on a master page** or;
- making some sort of jig to attach to your cutter so you can "cut and turn" without needing to measure or align. A few minutes of prep with some matte board can save you an hour or more at the other end of the job.

I would never use any sort of cut guides as described above for a professional (aka "out-of-house" or out-house) job.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add an extra page in the beginning of the document, create a rectangle the size of that page (probably with a fill for even easier handling) and print that with your other page(s).
Then you just have that extra sheet on top of your actual sheets, just use it for cutting and throw it away after you're done cutting.

I actually like the idea of turning this into a script, maybe I'll give it a try when I find the time.

What I always do, when I need to cut prototypes or tests in a quick way, is to cut the sides off clock-wise (or counter-clock-wise, doesn't matter) and then when I come to the last cut and have no crop marks anymore, I grab the strip of paper that I cut off in the previous (the third) cut – this one still has a crop mark on it –, put this on top of my stack, so the crop mark lands where it needs to go and then cut. Sounds complicated, but if you have the paper strip in front of you, you will know what I mean. ;)

For production cuts I just use crop marks on two sides (long edge and short edge) and cut the other side off by measuring.